# Авторизация через curl, коммандную строку, rest-консоль в Silex

Tags: curl, авторизация, rest, auth, silex

Пишу проект на силекс, пришло вот такое тз :

> ### Настроить авторизацию
>
> Есть необходимость авторизовывать пользователя через форму логина и по какому-нибудь API-ключу. В роли API-ключа может выступать та же пара логин:пароль, что и на форме.
>
> Суть: авторизация должна работать через форму и через `REST`-консоль или curl в командной строке. Главное, чтобы методы, доступные сейчас оценщику, авторизованному через форму, были доступны стороннему приложению, которое отправило логин и пароль оценщика.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Нужно опсать то, что уже есть и в чём конкретно проблема.

Comment: Что конкретно нужно описать?

Comment: есть ли уже какая-то авторизация и как она работает? В чём конкретно сейчас проблема? Что не получается? Желательно добавить связанные с задачей фрагменты кода. Вопрос получился слишком абстрактный, на него трудно дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: Есть обычная авторизация через форму, через Rest Console в phpstorm пытаюсь авторизоваться, не получается. Вот здесь брал реализацию авторизации http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-authentication-provider